# CodeIgniter add created by edit by based on logged in user

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have PHP application using CodeIgniter.
I also have 2 fields in every table
createdby, editby

I want to fill these fields with the userid of current logged user(from current session) when row created or edited.

Is there a quick way to do this

I am not familiar with CodeIgniter, I am familiar with hibernate which already have Event Listener you can use before updating or inserting any record. I am asking for something similar in CodeIgniter.

Comment: No Dear, I am not familiar with CodeIgniter, I am familiar with hibernate which already have Event Listener you can use before updating or inserting any record. I am asking for something similar. I will edit my question with this

Comment: when user logs in you set a $_SESSION with the user's id, when the row is created and the session value exists, you update, something like this?

Comment: Right, When any new raw created i will take id from session, and set createdby = userid same with update

Comment: so where is the problem?

Comment: In Hibernate you add a On New Record listener, any new records created ON ANY TABLE and before it goes to DB it call this Listener.  There you can do what ever you want like user createdby = current logged in user ID. So the question IS is there some thing like this in CodeIgniter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219691/discussion-between-thudner-and-vickel).

Answer (score 1):

Thank Vickel for help
CodeIgniter dose not have some thing like this